# Why does the Webform disappear after changing Submit button text in Form settings?

Tags: 6, webforms

I have created a **Webform** page called "Quick Quote".

It is working fine in the website. But when I change the "**Submit button text**" to a new value in `Advance Settings >> Form Setting` configuration, then the entire form (i.e Quick Quote page) disappears.

Why does it disappear, and how to enable it?

Comment: Do you get an entierly white page or just no webform?

Comment: May be it is redirecting you to webform confirmation page. And that page does not display the webform itself.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to know what's going on based on the limited information you've provided, but it could be permissions. If you don't have permissions to view the webform then you won't see it.

The scenario you've described might occur if you are configuring the webform while logged in, then testing it while logged out (or in another browser) as an anonymous user that does not have permissions to view.

Comment: The Webform I was created is working fine. I just try to change the name of Submit button to a new value (eg. "Click Here"). I changed it to new value and save it (in "Submit button text"). Then after it is disappeared.

Comment: Its worked fine for me on many occassions...is there any custom code added to alter the webform from your end? or any other module that interacts with your webform module installed? any details on this would be useful. Also suggest that you check the module's issue list if this has been previously reported...

Comment: I didn't add any custom code to Webform module, and I am using lot of modules, but I think this modules are not interact with webform modules.